# Есть ли альтернативный способ добавления в кортеж?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.x, tuple, кортежи

Пытаюсь добавить значения в кортеж так:

```
#!/usr/local/lib/python3

q = (1, 2, 3)
e = q + (5,)
print(e)
```

Этот способ работает, но не красиво. Потому что приходится после пятёрки добавлять запятую. А без запятой этот способ не работает:

> TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "int") to tuple

Скажите пожалуйста, не существует ли другого способа добавления значения в кортеж?

UPD:

```
#!/usr/local/lib/python3

q = (1, 2, 3)
print(id(q))
q = q + (5,)
print(q)
print(id(q))
```

видно, что id не изменился: https://i.yapx.ru/DZVAd.png

Comment: Можно ещё так: e = (*q, 5). Все эти неудобства вызваны тем фактом что tuple - immutable объект

Comment: «видно, что id не изменился» — видно что очень даже изменился

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Кортеж (`tuple`) это неизменяемая коллекция, поэтому вопрос о добавлении в нее элемента просто странный :)

А вот тут, вы например:

```
q = (1, 2, 3)
e = q + (5,)
```

Не добавили элемент в кортеж, а создали новый.

---

Аналогом кортежа будет список (`list`):

```
q = [1, 2, 3]
q.append(5)
print(q)  # [1, 2, 3, 5]
```

---

**UPD.**

Создается новый объект:

```
>>> a = (1, 2, 3)
>>> hex(id(a))
'0x202dfc73870'
>>> a += (5,)
>>> hex(id(a))
'0x202dfc740e8'
```

Или вот еще:

```
>>> a = (1, 2, 3)
>>> hex(id(a))
'0x202dfc73900'
>>> b = a + (5,)
>>> hex(id(a))
'0x202dfc73900'
>>> hex(id(b))
'0x202dfc740e8'
```

У `a` id не поменялся, т.к. по этой ссылке остался старый кортеж (`(1, 2, 3)`), но в `b` уже новый, который был создан при сложении кортежей

Comment: Я привёл не совсем удачный пример. Вот лучше: https://ideone.com/SKewWc 
здесь видно, что id не изменился, следовательно в кортеж было именно добавлено значение...

Comment: @rettoryh13, приведите, плиз, код в комментарий или в вопрос. А насчет вашего кода предположу, что тот выполнялся как есть, т.е. питон мог оптимизировать кортеж

Comment: ps: странно, python, установленный в моей ОС показывает одинаковые id, а по приведенной выше ссылке - разные. Видимо, зависит от реализации

Comment: @rettoryh13 но id всё же изменился.

Comment: @rettoryh13 https://i.yapx.ru/DZVAd.png

Comment: @rettoryh13 смотрите шесть последних цифр.